# I have error, when I build a Flutter project on the simulator iPhone 14 PRO iOS 17.0

Tags: xcodebuild

I have:

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.9, on macOS 13.5.2 22G91 darwin-arm64, locale ru-AE)
    [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    [✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    [✓] VS Code (version 1.85.2)
    [✓] Connected device (4 available)
    [✓] Network resources
```

when I build a Flutter project on the simulator iPhone 14 PRO iOS 17.0

I have error:

```
    Error output from Xcode build:
    2024-02-15 22:45:30.818 xcodebuild[70778:336554] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState:                DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CAD3DE6E-FA08-43EE-8401-4A2CF5DC1A5B, OS:17.0, name:iPhone 14   Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CAD3DE6E-FA08-43EE-8401-4A2CF5DC1A5B, OS:17.0, name:iPhone 14 Pro }
    ** BUILD FAILED **
    Xcode's output:
    Writing result bundle at path:       /var/folders/s7/zz5l021j7jq0d45kqm669ntm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.Xc0J6B/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirBrK331/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    /Users/ildargarifullin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner- feaomoxzzwywhraqqwkrahxboatu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug- iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-5D91779677A54A9385652DDA.sh: line 2:   /Users/ildargarifullin/Developer/applications/flutter: No such file or directory
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    note: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because the option to    run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project   'Runner')
    note: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because the option to  run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project  'Runner')
     warning: Run script build phase '[firebase_crashlytics] Crashlytics Upload Symbols' will be   run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add   output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based    on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
     Result bundle written to path:
  /var/folders/s7/zz5l021j7jq0d45kqm669ntm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.Xc0J6B/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirBrK331/temporary_xcresult_bundle
     Could not build the application for the simulator.
     Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
```

I did:

1. xcode -> Signing & Capabilities -> Signing -> Automatically manage signing -> OFF/ON
2. changed: to config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0' from to config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0 / 14.0'